# Creating homogeneous groups of areas from raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clustering, spatial-cluster

I'm trying to create homogeneous groups of areas from a raster which contain elevations data (in the red area).

[image]

currently I am doing it manually creating new polygons for each groups.

[image]

Is there a way to do it automatically using QGIS?

Comment: So, basically you are creating `contour`lines?

Comment: I want to create polygons which contains the same range of elevation data from a raster. Thank you

Comment: So, contour lines. Maybe converted to polygons, but contour lines. Have a look at `raster - extraction - contour lines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GDAL: it has a function `contour polygons` (version 2.4 or later) as part of [gdal_contour](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_contour.html).  It is accessible from the QGIS processing toolbox. If you don't find the entry `contour polygons` there, just use the `contour` tool and set the parameter `-p`: it creates polygons instead of lines - you can set this in the `Additional command-line parameters [optional]` box. See the link above for details.